# Creating a field thats connected with another in Django

Tags: html, django, forms, django-forms

The thing is that I'd like to create a field with a title that shows available titles depending on the artist's choice in the field above.
For example, if a user selects "Drake" in the artist field, only the titles for that artist will be displayed in the title field.
I'm completely stuck. Could you give me a hint how to solve the problem?
I was wandering if I have to change my models.py by adding some kind of One-To-Many relationship or is there diffrent method?

Webpage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1Jk.png)

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class SpotifyData(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    chart = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    streams = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['title']),
            models.Index(fields=['rank']),
            models.Index(fields=['date']),
            models.Index(fields=['artist']),
            models.Index(fields=['region']),
            models.Index(fields=['chart']),
            ]
```

My view.py file:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from django.shortcuts import render
from spotify_data.models import SpotifyData
from spotify_data.charts import (make_song_rank_changes_chart,
)

from typing import Any, Dict
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class HomeView(ListView):

    model = SpotifyData
    context_object_name = "record"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["records_all"] = SpotifyData.objects.all().count()

        return context

class SongRankChangesChart(TemplateView):

    model = SpotifyData
    context_object_name = "rank_changes"
    
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        start = '2019-01-01'
        end = '2020-01-01'
        ch_region = SpotifyData.objects.values("region").order_by("region").distinct()
        ch_chart = SpotifyData.objects.values("chart").order_by("chart").distinct()
        ch_artist = SpotifyData.objects.values("artist").order_by("artist").distinct()
        ch_title = SpotifyData.objects.values("title").order_by("title").distinct()

        data_filtered = SpotifyData.objects.filter(date__range=(start, end), artist = ch_artist[0], 
                            title=ch_title[0], region=ch_region[0], chart=ch_chart[0]).values()
       
        data = data_filtered.values_list("date", "rank")
       
        fig = make_song_rank_changes_chart(data, start, end, ch_artist, ch_title)

        chart = fig.to_html()

        context = {"chart": chart,
                "ch_title": ch_title,
                "ch_region": ch_region,
                "ch_chart": ch_chart,
                "ch_artist": ch_artist,
        }

        return context
```

And html template song_rank_changes_chart.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <body>
      <div div class ="form_box">
        <form method="GET" name="chart_1" action="{% url 'song_rank_changes_chart' %}" >
          {% csrf_token %}

          <div>
            Region
            <input list="list_of_regions" id="1" placeholder="Choose region"
                aria-label="Search" name="region">
            <datalist id="list_of_regions">
                {% for name in ch_region %}
                <option value="{{name.region}}">
                  {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>
          
          <div>
            Chart
            <input list="list_of_charts" id="2" placeholder="Choose chart" aria-label="Search"
                 name="chart">
            <datalist id="list_of_charts">
                {% for name in ch_chart %}
                <option value="{{name.chart}}">
                  {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>

          <div>
            Artist
            <input list="list_of_artists" id="3" placeholder="Choose artist" aria-label="Search"
                 name="artist">
            <datalist id="list_of_artists">
                {% for name in ch_artist %}
                <option value="{{name.artist}}">
                  {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>

          <div>
            Title
            <input list="list_of_titles" id="4" placeholder="Choose title" aria-label="Search"
                 name="title">
            <datalist id="list_of_titles">
                {% for name in ch_title %}
                <option value="{{name.title}}">
                  {% endfor %}
            </datalist>
          </div>

          <div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="chart_box">
        {{ chart|safe }}
      </div>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

The only information I found led me to change the model however I don't know how to do that for my example or if it is necessary. I also don't know how to combine this later with fields in html and queryset.

Comment: Do you know what a foreign key is?

Comment: see this link , you can use group_by

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp                        
 for foreign-key
https://www.educba.com/django-foreign-key/

Comment: I think you should use foreign key in your models,
Look at my code

https://github.com/seyedmo30/mo30/blob/main/general/models.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use foreign key in your models,
Look at my code

```
class Artist(models.Model):


    
    name = models.CharField( max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
```

edit models.py

```
from django.db import models

class SpotifyData(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
rank = models.IntegerField()
date = models.DateField()
artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
region = models.CharField(max_length=20)
chart = models.CharField(max_length=8)
streams = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['title']),
        models.Index(fields=['rank']),
        models.Index(fields=['date']),
        models.Index(fields=['artist']),
        models.Index(fields=['region']),
        models.Index(fields=['chart']),
        ]
```